# yarn install starts failing randomly with tar content of undefined failed

Tags: runtime-error, yarnpkg, tar

I woke up today to create android and iOS dev builds for my expo managed project and I see this error in the logs. I've tried almost everything and I really need some help now. I deleted my node_modules and yarn.lock files to reinstall them again , but now I cant event run yarn install.

error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/3.0.0/-/3.0.0-3.0.0.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "Invalid tar header. Maybe the tar is corrupted or it needs to be gunzipped?"

[image]

Comment: Please post the error as a text, and not a screenshot.